# Вылетает Gulp при ошибке в синтаксисе sass/css файла

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Вылетает `Gulp` при ошибке в синтаксисе `sass`-файла, хотелось бы найти решение в котором при ошибке `gulp` не **ломается**.

Comment: Дополните вопрос ошибкой которую вы получаете и содержимым файла конфигурации gulp.

Comment: Подключил всётаки пакет plumb и всё заработало, вот только когда меняю line-height , через бурбон **например**`line-height: em(55px)` ругается некрасиво


`WARNING: [Bourbon] [Deprecation] em is deprecated and will be removed in 5.0.0
.
Backtrace:
        node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/functions/_px-to-em.scss:8,
in function `em`
        app/sass/header.sass:9
`

Comment: сделал так npm I bourbon@4.2.7 и всё заработало :)

Comment: Оформите как ответ, что вы сделали, чтоб и другим людям с такой проблемой помогло.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В терминале установил пакет **plumber**

Код в директе проекта  :

```
npm install --save-dev gulp-plumber
```

Код в **gulpfile.js**

```
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');

gulp.src('./src/*.ext')
    .pipe(plumber())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
```

То есть под каждым таском, где нужно выловить ошибки, после src пишем:

```
.pipe(plumber())
```